# JQuery how to loop through multiple JSON files to build quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm stuck & I need your help please.
I'm building a front-end for a quiz. For some reason, the back-end provides 3 json files.
JSON1 gives me category and title (https://api.myjson.com/bins/nilct). JSON2 gives me questions (https://api.myjson.com/bins/1178p1). JSON3 possible answers (https://api.myjson.com/bins/qhft1).

I need to loop through JSON1 and write categories and titles. Loop through JSON2 and write the question for that title. Loop through JSON3 and write possible answers for each question.

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bigMain" class="hide">

    </div>  

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/refactor3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript file:

```
var request1 = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/nilct',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

        var key, jsoncount = 0;
        for(key in data) {
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                jsoncount++;
            }
        }
        $(data).each(function(index, value){
            var categoryId = value.id;
            var catCategory = value.category;
            var catHeader = value.header;
            var catOrderNum = value.question;

            var getSectionPlace = document.getElementById('bigMain');
            var maturidadeSection = 
                '<section id="' + categoryId + '">\
                    <div class="section-top">\
                        <p class="title optionsTitle '+ catCategory +' titleFor_'+ categoryId + '">\
                        ' + catCategory + '\
                        </p>\
                        <hr class="hideOnMobile">\
                        <h1 class="top-title">'+ catHeader +'</h1>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="section-bottom">\
                    And this is bottom div\
                    </div>\
                </section>';


        function makeSections(){
            $( maturidadeSection ).appendTo( getSectionPlace );
        }
        makeSections();

        });
    }
}),

request2 = $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1178p1',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //console.table(data);
            var key, jsoncount = 0;
            for(key in data) {
                if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                jsoncount++;

                }
            }

            $(data).each(function(index, value){
                var questionId = value.id;
                var questionText = value.question;
                var questionOrderNum = value.orderNum;
                var questionType = value.type;
                var questionBelongsTo = value.category_id;

    /**
     * Get the place to put content inside sections and place it
     */
            var getQuestionPlace = document.getElementsByClassName('section-bottom');
            var questionToPlace = '<div class="question question' + questionBelongsTo + '">\
                                        <p class="questionP questionId_'+questionId+'">\
                                            ' + questionText + 
                                        '</p>\
                                        <ul id="questionId-'+ questionId +'" class="answerContainer">\
                                            <li>TESTS</li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                   </div>'

                                   function makeQuestions(){
                                       $( questionToPlace ).appendTo( getQuestionPlace );
                                    }
                                    makeQuestions();

            });

        }    
    }),
request3 = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qhft1',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var key, jsoncount = 0;
        for(key in data) {
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            jsoncount++;
            }
        }

        $(data).each(function(index, value){
            var answerId = value.id;
            var answerText = value.answer;
            var answerOrderNum = value.orderNum;

    /**
     * Get the place to put content inside sections and place it
     */
            var getAnswerPlace = document.getElementsByClassName('answerContainer');
            var answerToPlace = '<li><input type="radio" name="'+ answerOrderNum +'" value="'+ answerText +'">\
                                    '+ answerText +'\
                                </li>'

                                   function makeAnswers(){
                                       $( answerToPlace ).appendTo( getAnswerPlace );
                                    }
                                    makeAnswers();

            });
        }    
    });
```

But this is not working as I can't seem to controll what happens in what loop and is getting a big mess.

Can anyone help me with a way to do this? And having all data from one JSON is not available.

Thanks in adavnce!

Comment: *this is not working* - sounds like a problem ... can you describe what the code does and how it differs from what you expect it to do. Also, check the browser developer tools console for errors - are there any?

Comment: there seems at least to be a missing `}}),` just before `request2 = $.ajax({`

Comment: Thank you. That was my mistake while placing and cleaning code to make shorter. The problem is that it creates something like:
Title A
questionA
answer A1
answer A2
answer B1
...
questionB
answer A1
answer A2
answer B1
...
question B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **fropt**, welcome to StackOverflow :)

*de um tuga para outro, Bem Vindo!*

secondly... your question.

Well, I can see a mess in that code, so I would suggest, instead of just helping to fix it... a different path, so you can have total control in what's going on and making it also easier to improve and fix any code:

Because you are repeating your code and using small chunks of HTML, I would strongly suggest a very small tool, like [JsRender](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsrender) from one of our [members](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054484/borismoore) (you could use [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) or [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) as well, but they are a bit bigger and with too much functionality we will not even use)

for such, I would then do:

- have an array with all your URL's
- go through them all
- to be easier to manipulate, append child data to parent object
- save all data into a global object
- render your template with the gathered data

a caveat:

if **you can use Promises**, you can take advantage of firing all 3 requests at once and wait until all are done and go from there... for example:

```
  var settings = [
    // categories
    'https://api.myjson.com/bins/nilct',
    // questions
    'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1178p1',
    // answers
    'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qhft1',
  ];


  Promise.all([
    getData(settings[0]),
    getData(settings[1]),
    getData(settings[2])
  ]).then(function(allData) {
    var categories = allData[0],
        questions = allData[1],
        answers = allData[2];

    // append all categoties to our global object
    formData = categories;
    // append all questions to each category
    formData.forEach(function(x) {
      x.questions = questions;
      // append all answers to each question
      x.questions.forEach(function(y) {
        y.answers = answers;
      });
    });

  processData(formData, '#tmplForm', '#main-quiz');
```

If you can't (IE11 can't work with promises for example), I've written almost the same code.

Here's my take if I would have your code problem...

```js
$(function() {

  var formData = [];
  var settings = [
    // categories
    'https://api.myjson.com/bins/nilct',
    // questions
    'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1178p1',
    // answers
    'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qhft1',
  ];
  
  
  // if Promises are available, use this code
  /*
  Promise.all([
    getData(settings[0]),
    getData(settings[1]),
    getData(settings[2])
  ]).then(function(allData) {
    var categories = allData[0],
        questions = allData[1],
        answers = allData[2];
    
    formData = categories;
      // now that we have all questions, append them to categories
      formData.forEach(function(x) {
        x.questions = questions;
        // now that we have all answers, append them to questions
        x.questions.forEach(function(y) {
          y.answers = answers;
        });
      });
      
    processData(formData, '#tmplForm', '#main-quiz');
    $('.btn-submit').show();
  }); */
  
  // if you can't use Promises, use the code below
  $.getJSON(settings[0], function(data) { 
    formData = data;
    
    $.getJSON(settings[1], function(data) {
      
      // now that we have all questions, append them to categories
      formData.forEach(function(x) {
        x.questions = data;
      });
      
      $.getJSON(settings[2], function(data) {
        
        // now that we have all answers, append them to questions
        formData.forEach(function(x) {
          x.questions.forEach(function(y) {
            y.answers = data;
          });
        });
        
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(formData, null, 4))
        processData(formData, '#tmplForm', '#main-quiz');
        $('.btn-submit').show();
      });
    });
  });
  /* */

  // submit button event
  $('.btn-submit').on('click', submitData);
});

function processData(data, scriptTmpl, appendTo) {
  // get the template
  var template = $.templates(scriptTmpl);
  // convert to HTML
  var htmlOutput = template.render(data);
  // append to html element
  $(appendTo).append(htmlOutput);
}

function submitData(evt) {
  var answersData = [];
  var questions = $('#main-quiz .question');
  console.log('FOUND ' + questions.length + ' questions');
  
  questions.each(function (i, q) {
    var question = $(q);
    var answer = $(q).find('input[type="radio"]:checked'); // selected answer
    answersData.push({
      id: answer.data('id') || '', // the answer id
      answer: answer.val() || '' // the actual answer
    });
  });

  // let's see those answers
  console.log(JSON.stringify(answersData, null, 4));
}

// it's only used on the Promises code
function getData(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) { resolve(data); });
  });
}
```

```css
.btn-submit { display: none; }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrender/1.0.5/jsrender.min.js"></script>

  <div id="main-quiz"></div>
  <button class="btn-submit">Submit answers</button>
  
  <script id="tmplForm" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <section id="section-{{:id}}" data-id="{{:id}}">
      
      <div class="section-top">
        <hr class="hideOnMobile">
        <h1 class="top-title">#{{:id}} {{:category}}</h1>
        <p class="title optionsTitle {{:category}} titleFor_{{:id}}">{{:header}}</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="section-bottom">
        And this is bottom div
        
        {{for questions}}
          <div data-id="{{:id}}" class="question question{{:category_id}}" data-parentid="{{:#parent.data.id}}">
            <p class="questionP questionId_{{:id}}">{{:question}}</p>
            
            <ul id="questionId-{{:id}}" class="answerContainer">
              
              {{for answers}}
                <li data-id="{{:id}}" data-parentid="{{:#parent.parent.data.id}}">
                  <label for="answer_{{:#parent.parent.parent.parent.data.id}}_{{:#parent.parent.data.id}}_{{:id}}">
                    <input data-id="{{:#parent.parent.parent.parent.data.id}}_{{:#parent.parent.data.id}}_{{:id}}" type="radio" 
                    name="answer_{{:#parent.parent.parent.parent.data.id}}_{{:#parent.parent.data.id}}" 
                    id="answer_{{:#parent.parent.parent.parent.data.id}}_{{:#parent.parent.data.id}}_{{:id}}" 
                    value="{{:answer}}" />
                    {{:answer}}
                  </label>
                </li>
              {{/for}}
              
            </ul>
          </div>
        {{/for}}
        
      </div>
    </section>
  </script>
```

There's a lot to take into, but separating the HTML from your JavaScript is the best idea as you can focus on what does one and the other and never worry if you are missing a closing tag or a comma somewhere ... makes it even easier to follow as well :)

the only thing you might not understand at first is the access to parent data, but you can see it [well explained in the documentation](https://www.jsviews.com/#parentdata).

P.S. I've edited a bit of your original HTML as well to make it easier to see... might not be the output you want, but it's only to better demonstrate the hole scenario

P.P.S. here's the full [example on JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/wimetix/1/edit?output)

Comment: ahah Obrigado! Tugas rule :)
Thank you so much for the quality and deepness of detail in your solution. It really changes the game for me. 
You rock!!   :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with when to import files.
The problem is solved by loading the files at once and processing the json at once.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/nilct',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function(title) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1178p1',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'get',
      cache: false,
      success: function(qustion) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qhft1',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'get',
          cache: false,
          success: function(answer) {
            randerHtml(title, qustion, answer);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

function randerHtml(title, qustion, answer) {
  console.log(title, qustion, answer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, but that was a mistake I made while placing code here. Seemed to have cleaned more than I should. I'll edit the question but the real issue remains.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?
Do you see 'request2', 'request3' sometimes on every refresh?

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot. Makes sense just by reading it. I'll vote right after! Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/nilct',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function(cats) {
    drawCats(cats);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1178p1',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'get',
      cache: false,
      success: function(qustions) {
        drawQuestions(qustions);
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qhft1',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'get',
          cache: false,
          success: function(answers) {
            drawAnswers(answers);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});


function drawCats(cats){
    $(cats).each(function(index, value){
        var categoryId = value.id;
        var catCategory = value.category;
        var catHeader = value.header;
        var catOrderNum = value.question;

        var maturidadeSection = 
            '<section id="cat_' + categoryId + '" class="cats" data-id="' + categoryId + '">\
                <div class="section-top">\
                    <p class="title optionsTitle '+ catCategory +' titleFor_'+ categoryId + '">\
                    ' + catCategory + '\
                    </p>\
                    <hr class="hideOnMobile">\
                    <h1 class="top-title">'+ catHeader +'</h1>\
                </div>\
                <div class="section-bottom">\
                And this is bottom div\
                </div>\
            </section>';
        $("#bigMain").append(maturidadeSection);
    });
}

function drawQuestions(qustions){

    $(qustions).each(function(index, value){
        var questionId = value.id;
        var questionText = value.question;
        var questionOrderNum = value.orderNum;
        var questionType = value.type;
        var questionBelongsTo = value.category_id;

        $(".cats").each(function(){
        if($(this).data("id") == questionBelongsTo) {
            var questionToPlace = '<div class="question question' + questionBelongsTo + '">\
                            <p class="questionP questionId_'+questionId+'">\
                                        ' + questionText + 
                                    '</p>\
                                    <ul id="questionId-'+ questionId +'" class="answerContainer">\
                                    </ul>\
                               </div>';
                    $( questionToPlace ).appendTo($(".section-bottom",this));

            }
         });

    });
}

function drawAnswers(answers){
    console.log(answers)
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed El-sayed, thank you! I'll give it a try :)